# How to set up a jmeter test that loops through each value in a CSV file?

Tags: csv, foreach, jmeter

I have a CSV file containing a several lines of data.

I have a custom Java sampler, which uses one line of data at a time.

How do I set up a test where, the CSV file is preprocessed and each line is fed into the java sampler every time it is run? (i.e. everytime the java sampler is run the next line in the CSV file should be used as an input).

My attempt is described below, but I am not seeing any output and the java request is not even running.

This is how I set up the test:
[image]

and This is how I set up the CSV config:

[image]

This is how I set up the ForEach controller:
[image]

This is the Custom Java Sampler code I used for the Java Request, to take the variable in:
[image]

Comment: Why not loop with CSV Data Set?

Comment: @user7294900 please see added details to the question

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ForEach controller which is used for **set of related** of variables, Add [Loop  Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and put under/ inside it the CSV Data Set Config

Change the CSV's configuration: Stop thread on EOF =TRUE And Recyle on EOF = FALSE

You will read each CSV line in a loop until end of file.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java Request sampler configuration is not visible so my assumption may be incorrect, however my expectation is that you are using the wrong method. In order to get the `RequestLine` variable value from the Java Request sampler you need to use [JavaSamplerContext.getJMeterVariables()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JavaSamplerContext.html#getJMeterVariables--) function like:

```
RequestLine = javaSamplerContext.getJMeterVariables().get("RequestLine");
```

Few more troubleshooting tips:

- Double check your `RequestLine` variable value using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination
- Check *jmeter.log* file - normally you should be able to figure out the root cause of the problem from there
- You can run JMeter with [debugging enabled](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-notes-3745703.html#JDK-8041435) like:

  ```
  java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000 -jar ApacheJMeter.jar
  ```

  and connect Eclipse to JMeter so you can use debugger so see where exactly your Java Request sampler fails.

See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more information on JMeter tests troubleshooting.